# ¿Cómo implementar Natural Sort en <select> html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, ordenamiento

Quiero ordenar los elementos de un select html con javascript, los elementos a ordenar son alfanuméricos por lo que se deben ordenar con un algoritmo de ordenamiento natural (Natural Sort), para lograrlo estoy ocupando el algoritmo creado por [JIM PALMER](http://www.overset.com/2008/09/01/javascript-natural-sort-algorithm-with-unicode-support/) y extrayendo tanto el texto como los values de cada `<option>`. Sin embargo no logro unirlos para crear un nuevo `<select>` ordenado con el texto y el value correcto.

Mi pregunta es: **¿Puedo lograr lo que deseo de esa manera, o puedo hacerlo de una manera más directa?**

El código que tengo hasta ahora es el siguiente:

```js
function naturalSort (a, b) {
    var re = /(^-?[0-9]+(\.?[0-9]*)[df]?e?[0-9]?$|^0x[0-9a-f]+$|[0-9]+)/gi,
        sre = /(^[ ]*|[ ]*$)/g,
        dre = /(^([\w ]+,?[\w ]+)?[\w ]+,?[\w ]+\d+:\d+(:\d+)?[\w ]?|^\d{1,4}[\/\-]\d{1,4}[\/\-]\d{1,4}|^\w+, \w+ \d+, \d{4})/,
        hre = /^0x[0-9a-f]+$/i,
        ore = /^0/,
        i = function(s) { return naturalSort.insensitive && (''+s).toLowerCase() || ''+s },
        // convert all to strings strip whitespace
        x = i(a).replace(sre, '') || '',
        y = i(b).replace(sre, '') || '',
        // chunk/tokenize
        xN = x.replace(re, '\0$1\0').replace(/\0$/,'').replace(/^\0/,'').split('\0'),
        yN = y.replace(re, '\0$1\0').replace(/\0$/,'').replace(/^\0/,'').split('\0'),
        // numeric, hex or date detection
        xD = parseInt(x.match(hre)) || (xN.length != 1 && x.match(dre) && Date.parse(x)),
        yD = parseInt(y.match(hre)) || xD && y.match(dre) && Date.parse(y) || null,
        oFxNcL, oFyNcL;
    // first try and sort Hex codes or Dates
    if (yD)
        if ( xD < yD ) return -1;
        else if ( xD > yD ) return 1;
    // natural sorting through split numeric strings and default strings
    for(var cLoc=0, numS=Math.max(xN.length, yN.length); cLoc < numS; cLoc++) {
        // find floats not starting with '0', string or 0 if not defined (Clint Priest)
        oFxNcL = !(xN[cLoc] || '').match(ore) && parseFloat(xN[cLoc]) || xN[cLoc] || 0;
        oFyNcL = !(yN[cLoc] || '').match(ore) && parseFloat(yN[cLoc]) || yN[cLoc] || 0;
        // handle numeric vs string comparison - number < string - (Kyle Adams)
        if (isNaN(oFxNcL) !== isNaN(oFyNcL)) { return (isNaN(oFxNcL)) ? 1 : -1; }
        // rely on string comparison if different types - i.e. '02' < 2 != '02' < '2'
        else if (typeof oFxNcL !== typeof oFyNcL) {
            oFxNcL += '';
            oFyNcL += '';
        }
        if (oFxNcL < oFyNcL) return -1;
        if (oFxNcL > oFyNcL) return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

var texts = [];
var values = [];
var sel = document.getElementById('order_select');
for (var i=0, n=sel.options.length;i<n;i++) {
  if (sel.options[i].text) {
    texts.push(sel.options[i].text);
  }
  if (sel.options[i].value) {
    values.push(sel.options[i].value);
  }
}

var a = texts.sort(naturalSort);

$.each(a, function( index, value ) {
  $('#colocar').append("<option>"+value+"</option>");
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
<select class="orden" name="order_select" id="order_select">
  <option value="1">aab1</option>
  <option value="2">aab2</option>
  <option value="0">aab0</option>
  <option value="10">aab10</option>
  <option value="11">aab11</option>
  <option value="21">aab21</option>
  <option value="20">aab20</option>
  <option value="3">aab23</option>
</select>
<select class="otra" name="colocar" id="colocar">

</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No comprendo, ¿qué es lo que buscas? ¿No funciona el algoritmo de ordenación? ¿Mejorar el algoritmo de ordenación?

Comment: Hola @AlvaroMontoro, el algoritmo si funciona, lo que quiero lograr es ordenar el select sin que se pierdan los values de cada `<option>`, si te fijas en el select donde coloco el arreglo ordenado no tiene values, ya que  no se como mantener el orden de los mismos, o mejor dicho no se como lograr colocar el value correspondiente a cada texto del `<option>`.

Comment: Ok, entendido. Escribiendo una respuesta :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es, en lugar de crear dos arrays uno con el contenido de cada  `option` y otro con el valor, puedes crear un único array con objetos del tipo:

```
{
    "valor": valor-del-option,
    "texto": texto-del-option
}
```

Entonces le haces sort a ese array, y al principio de la función de ordenación, asegúrate de que el valor de `a` y `b` se reasigna con `a.texto` y `b.texto`. Sin necesidad de hacer más cambios, ya se ordena el array de objetos perfectamente.

Por último, lo único que queda es recrear el select con el `$.each`, pero eso también es sencillo: `value.valor` tendrá el valor del `option` original, y `value.texto` tendrá el texto.

Aquí te dejo el código

```js
function naturalSort (a, b) {

    // sobreescribe los valores de a y b sólo dentro de la función
    a = a.texto;
    b = b.texto;

    var re = /(^-?[0-9]+(\.?[0-9]*)[df]?e?[0-9]?$|^0x[0-9a-f]+$|[0-9]+)/gi,
        sre = /(^[ ]*|[ ]*$)/g,
        dre = /(^([\w ]+,?[\w ]+)?[\w ]+,?[\w ]+\d+:\d+(:\d+)?[\w ]?|^\d{1,4}[\/\-]\d{1,4}[\/\-]\d{1,4}|^\w+, \w+ \d+, \d{4})/,
        hre = /^0x[0-9a-f]+$/i,
        ore = /^0/,
        i = function(s) { return naturalSort.insensitive && (''+s).toLowerCase() || ''+s },
        // convert all to strings strip whitespace
        x = i(a).replace(sre, '') || '',
        y = i(b).replace(sre, '') || '',
        // chunk/tokenize
        xN = x.replace(re, '\0$1\0').replace(/\0$/,'').replace(/^\0/,'').split('\0'),
        yN = y.replace(re, '\0$1\0').replace(/\0$/,'').replace(/^\0/,'').split('\0'),
        // numeric, hex or date detection
        xD = parseInt(x.match(hre)) || (xN.length != 1 && x.match(dre) && Date.parse(x)),
        yD = parseInt(y.match(hre)) || xD && y.match(dre) && Date.parse(y) || null,
        oFxNcL, oFyNcL;
    // first try and sort Hex codes or Dates
    if (yD)
        if ( xD < yD ) return -1;
        else if ( xD > yD ) return 1;
    // natural sorting through split numeric strings and default strings
    for(var cLoc=0, numS=Math.max(xN.length, yN.length); cLoc < numS; cLoc++) {
        // find floats not starting with '0', string or 0 if not defined (Clint Priest)
        oFxNcL = !(xN[cLoc] || '').match(ore) && parseFloat(xN[cLoc]) || xN[cLoc] || 0;
        oFyNcL = !(yN[cLoc] || '').match(ore) && parseFloat(yN[cLoc]) || yN[cLoc] || 0;
        // handle numeric vs string comparison - number < string - (Kyle Adams)
        if (isNaN(oFxNcL) !== isNaN(oFyNcL)) { return (isNaN(oFxNcL)) ? 1 : -1; }
        // rely on string comparison if different types - i.e. '02' < 2 != '02' < '2'
        else if (typeof oFxNcL !== typeof oFyNcL) {
            oFxNcL += '';
            oFyNcL += '';
        }
        if (oFxNcL < oFyNcL) return -1;
        if (oFxNcL > oFyNcL) return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

// sólo necesitas un array en lugar de dos
var valores = [];
var sel = document.getElementById('order_select');
for (var i=0, n=sel.options.length;i<n;i++) {
  // añade un objeto al array en lugar de la cadena de texto
  valores.push({ 
    "valor": sel.options[i].value,  // el valor del option
    "texto":sel.options[i].text     // el texto del option
  });
}

// esto se mantiene igual :)
var a = valores.sort(naturalSort);

$.each(a, function( index, value ) {
  // como ahora es un array de objetos, accede a cada propiedad adecuadamente
  $('#colocar').append("<option value='" + value.valor + "'>"+value.texto+"</option>");
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
<select class="orden" name="order_select" id="order_select">
  <option value="1">aab1</option>
  <option value="2">aab2</option>
  <option value="0">aab0</option>
  <option value="10">aab10</option>
  <option value="11">aab11</option>
  <option value="21">aab21</option>
  <option value="20">aab20</option>
  <option value="3">aab23</option>
</select>
<select class="otra" name="colocar" id="colocar">

</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias @AlvaroMontoro, eso era lo que necesitaba, funcionó perfectamente.

Comment: De nada. Me alegra que te funcionase :)

Comment: una pregunta adicional, si quisiera ordenar el select sin necesidad de crear otro select para colocar los valores ordenados, cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: @JuanPinzón Una opción rápida: vacía el `select` original (`$("#order_select").html("");`) y vuelve a rellenarlo como haces con el nuevo que creas (sólo tendrías que cambiar el id: `$('#order_select').append(.....)`)

Comment: Gracias de nuevo @AlvaroMontoro, justo eso estaba pensando, lo logre vaciandolo primero con $('#order_select').html(""); y luego rellenandolo con el append(). Gracias!! :)